# iOS: Bluetooth LE peripheral no longer updating after coming back into range

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have written an iOS app that reads data from a TI SensorTag.  Following the advice Apple provides in the "Core Bluetooth Programming Guide", I have subscribed to the service characteristic's value by calling the peripheral object's `setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:` method.  Periodically, the peripheral calls the `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:` method to inform me the value of interest has changed, and I read it, as described in the documentation.

When I move the iOS device a certain distance from the SensorTag, the `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` method stops being called (apparently) because the two are "out-of-range".  But when I move the devices back "in-range", updating does not resume.  Somehow, my "peripheral" object no longer represents the real peripheral device.

What steps can I follow to 1) programmatically "notice" the peripheral is no longer "valid", and 2) re-connect to my device without user intervention?

Thanks!

--Bill

Comment: Is your `centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:` method being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your peripheral disconnects, the `centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error` callback is called. In this callback you can immediately start a connection request to the same peripheral with the `connectPeripheral:options:` method. This request will stay active until the connection happens. It doesn't require any user interaction.

Comment: Thank you, allprog.  I just verified the centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error callback is exactly what I need to move forward.  3 Cheers!